# selectCheckboxMenu primefaces return empty List

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, selectcheckboxmenu

I'm trying to get selected values from a `selectCheckboxMenu` using PrimeFaces 5.3 and JSF 2, but always the selection list is empty.

This is the HTML part:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="cours" value="#{etudiantController.checkedCours}"
    converter="#{coursConverter}" label="Liste cours available" multiple="true" 
    panelStyle="width:250px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{etudiantController.coursEtudiant}" var="coursEtd" 
        itemLabel="#{coursEtd.libelleCours}" itemValue="#{coursEtd.idCours}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Bean part:

```
private List<Cours> checkedCours;

for(Cours coursToAdd : checkedCours){
    System.out.println("enter ... !!!");
    coursService.addCours(coursToAdd);
}
```

Converter :

```
public class CoursConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        return component.getAttributes().get(value);
    }
    return null;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    }
    if (value instanceof Cours) {
        Cours cours = (Cours) value;
        String name = cours.getLibelleCours();
        return name;
    } else {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(value + " est un Cours non valide"));
    }
} }
```

The problem here is that it never enter in the block.

Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: And when are you getting the selected values? On form submit, right?

Comment: Yes, using submit.

Comment: Do you have added form tag to your xhtml?

Comment: I use this one : <h:form> from xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

Comment: That is correct, now do your `commandButton` or `commandLink` is inside the form?

Comment: <p:commandButton> inside, I can do add and delete operation in this form.

Comment: First of all, there is no `multiple` attribute support on `p:selectCheckboxMenu`. Secondly, what is the type of `etudiantController.checkedCours`? Also, did you try removing `converter`?

Comment: Your have not added the related part(s) of the code.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Well, I have never tried `p:selectCheckboxMenu` with custom list (`List<Cours>`) using converter (`CoursConverter`) as value for the component.

Comment: First, try changing your `List<Cours> checkedCours` to `String[] checkedCours` and remove converter to verify the simpler behavior of the component.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is your own answer? It is 'gone'....

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an Id to your converter and calling it using that id

```
@FacesConverter("coursConverter")
public class CoursConverter implements Converter {
    ...
}
```

--

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="cours" value="#{etudiantController.checkedCours}"
    converter="coursConverter" label="Liste cours available" multiple="true" 
    panelStyle="width:250px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{etudiantController.coursEtudiant}" var="coursEtd" 
    itemLabel="#{coursEtd.libelleCours}" itemValue="#{coursEtd.idCours}" />
```